# Programming exercise gone wrong

Tags: c#, list, multiple-instances

So I have this simple (for others) exercise where i need to create a pharmacy and add to that 2 types of drugs. I have one class called Drugs which contains the attributes of the drugs:

```
public class drugattr
    {
        public int id; 
        public string drugName; 
        public string DrugDesc; 
        public int drugIntensity ;

        public drugattr(int id, string drugName, string DrugDesc, int drugIntensity)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.drugName= drugName;
            this.DrugDesc = DrugDesc;
            this.drugIntensity = drugIntensity ;
        }
    }
```

Then i have a pharmacy class with the pharmacies attributes:

```
 public class pharmacyatrr
    {
        public string PharmacyName; 
        public string PharmacyTown; 
        public List<drugattr> Atrributes= null; // the list with the drugs' attributes 


        public pharmacyatrr(string pharmacyName, string pharmacyTown, List<drugattr> atrributes)
        {
            this.PharmacyName = pharmacyName;
            this.PharmacyTown = pharmacyTown;
            this.Atrributes = atrributes;
        }
```

and i have my main class where i need to create a pharmacy and assign to it a couple of drugs.

```
 public class Program : pharmacyatrr
    {
        public Program(string PharmacyName, string PharmacyTown , List<drugattr> Atrributes) : base(PharmacyName, PharmacyTown , Atrributes)
        {
            this.PharmacyName = pharmacyName;
            this.PharmacyTown = pharmacyTown;
            this.Atrributes = atrributes;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
           drugattr drugA = new drugattr(1, "DrugA_Name", "Very STrong", 20);
            drugattr drugB = new drugattr(2, "DrugB_Name", "Mild Strong", 8);

            pharmacyatrr pharmacy1 = new pharmacyatrr("PharmacyName", "Town", drugA); // the problem is here

        }
    }
```

So if I try to add drugB i get the expected error that it can only accept 3 parameters.

If i create a pharmacy2 with the same name and town but with drugB that wouldn't create a new pharmacy?

I need one pharmacy to have multiple drug entries...

any tips on how to solve this? I am fairly new to C# and programming so please don't go harsh on me!

Comment: You need to pass a list of drugs, not drugs themselves. You should have got a type error from that.

Comment: You only created `drugattr drugA`, but your parameter is a `List<drugattr>`. You need to pass in a collection. Add `drugA` to a list of drugattr.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Pretty much what everyone has said, but just the complete code.

Drugs Class

```
class DrugAttribute
    {
        public int id;
        public string drugName;
        public string drugDescription;
        public int drugIntensity;


        public DrugAttribute(int id, string drugName, string drugDescription, int drugIntensity)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.drugName = drugName;
            this.drugDescription = drugDescription;
            this.drugIntensity = drugIntensity;
        } 
    }
```

And the Pharmacy Class

```
 class PharmacyAtrribute
    {
        public string pharmacyName;
        public string pharmacyTown;
        public List<DrugAttribute> drugList = null;

        public PharmacyAtrribute(string pharmacyName, string pharmacyTown, List<DrugAttribute> drugList)
        {
            this.pharmacyName = pharmacyName;
            this.pharmacyTown = pharmacyTown;
            this.drugList = new List<DrugAttribute>(drugList);
        }
    }
```

And the main class

```
class Program : PharmacyAtrribute
    {
        public Program(string pharmacyName, string pharmacyTown, List<DrugAttribute> drugList) : base(pharmacyName, pharmacyTown, drugList)
        {
            this.pharmacyName = pharmacyName;
            this.pharmacyTown = pharmacyTown;
            this.drugList = new List<DrugAttribute>(drugList);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DrugAttribute drugA = new DrugAttribute(1, "DrugA_Name", "Very Strong", 20);
            DrugAttribute drugB = new DrugAttribute(2, "DrugB_Name", "Mild Strong", 8);

            List<DrugAttribute> listOfDrugs = new List<DrugAttribute>{ drugA, drugB };

            PharmacyAtrribute pharmacy1 = new PharmacyAtrribute("PharmacyName", "Town", listOfDrugs);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure you may have noticed I changed some of the names. I'll just give you a couple of helpful tips regarding naming conventions. For Classnames, Microsoft encourages use of the Pascal capitalization style. So in your case, `drugattr` would be `DrugAttr`. For variables and attributes, Camel Case is encouraged. So

```
public string PharmacyName; 
public string PharmacyTown; 
public List<drugattr> Atrributes= null;
```

should become

```
public string pharmacyName; 
public string pharmacyTown; 
public List<drugattr> atrributes= null;
```

For more about naming conventions, have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx

And with names, it's good to be as descriptive as possible, so calling your class `DrugAttributes` might be a good idea. Anyone who is reading your code will know exactly what it's about even without comments (Although comments are a must too).

Even if it's just a simple learning exercise, it's always good to practice with conventional styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list of drugs to match your List parameter in the pharmacyattr constructor.

Create a new list like:

`List<drugattr> drugList = new List<drugattr>();`

And add to the list like this:

`drugList.Add(drugA);`

You can then create your pharmacy with the slight adjustment of:

`pharmacyatrr pharmacy1 = new pharmacyatrr("PharmacyName", "Town", drugList);`

Comment: So i should leave  drugattr drugA = new drugattr(1, "DrugA_Name", "Very STrong", 20); and drugattr drugB = new drugattr(2, "DrugB_Name", "Mild Strong", 8); as they are and then add the drugList.Add(drugA); and drugList.Add(drugB);

Answer (score 1):

```
var drugs = new List<drugattr> { drugA, drugB };    
pharmacyatrr pharmacy1 = new pharmacyatrr("PharmacyName", "Town", drugs);
```